# Count(*) not working properly

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, count

I create the trigger A1 so that an article with a certain type, that is 'Bert' cannot be added more than once and it can have only 1 in the stock.
However, although i create the trigger, i can still add an article with the type 'Bert'. Somehow, the count returns '0' but when i run the same sql statement, it returns the correct number. It also starts counting properly if I drop the trigger and re-add it. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

```
TRIGGER A1 BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 l_count NUMBER;
 PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count FROM mytable WHERE article = :new.article;

    dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || l_count);
  IF l_count >0  THEN
    IF(:new.TYPEB = 'Bert') THEN 
      dbms_output.put_line('article already exists!');
      ROLLBACK; 
    END IF;
  ELSIF (:new.TYPEB = 'Bert' AND :new.stock_count>1) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('stock cannot have more than 1 of this article with type Bert');
    ROLLBACK; 
  END IF;
END;
```

This is the insert statement I use:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('Chip',1,9,1,'Bert');
```

Comment: Count does return 0 because when you first insert it there is no row in mytable where article is the same as the one you're trying to insert. The second time you run your sql statement ant the trigger fires it returns 1. The only explanation for this behaviour. When you drop the trigger do you also delete records that were added previously?

Comment: the output.putline keeps priting "Count: 0" every time I insert. Not only in the first time.

Comment: Why aren't you using a unique constraint for this?

Comment: i am really curious why the count statement returns 0 each time.

Comment: This style trigger can not work. Even if the trigger is fixed, two transactions adding a record at the same time can not see each other, because of isolation, and will allow the add.

Comment: Probably you did not commit previous inserts, it's important for autonomous transactions.

Comment: and using an autonomous transaction in a trigger can have unforseen consequences.  This feature should be using sparingly, mostly to a logging table.

Comment: Count(*) works as expected, but ROLLBACK within an autonomous transaction only rolls back that autonomous transaction and has no effect on the statement that caused the trigger to fire. Better use raise_application_error instead. BTW, an autonomous transaction doesn't see uncommited data, even from the same session! Dropping and recreating the trigger implicitely commits your transaction.

Comment: **Why** did you add the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION`? And are you checking for exceptions after performing your `INSERT`?

Comment: @BobJarvis I don't think any exceptions are thrown in the given code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points. First, you are misusing the autonomous transaction pragma. It is meant for separate transactions you need to commit or rollback independently of the main transaction. You are using it to rollback the main transaction -- and you never commit if there is no error.

And those "unforeseen consequences" someone mentioned? One of them is that your count always returns 0. So remove the pragma both because it is being misused and so the count will return a proper value.

Another thing is don't have commits or rollbacks within triggers. Raise an error and let the controlling code do what it needs to do. I know the rollbacks were because of the pragma. Just don't forget to remove them when you remove the pragma.

The following trigger works for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_mytable_biu 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.TYPEB = 'Bert') -- Don't even execute unless this is Bert
DECLARE
    L_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT  COUNT(*) INTO L_COUNT
    FROM    MYTABLE 
    WHERE   ARTICLE = :NEW.ARTICLE
        AND TYPEB = :NEW.TYPEB;

    IF L_COUNT > 0  THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Bert already exists!' );
    ELSIF :NEW.STOCK_COUNT > 1 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Can''t insert more than one Bert!' );
    END IF;
END;
```

However, it's not a good idea for a trigger on a table to separately access that table. Usually the system won't even allow it -- this trigger won't execute at all if changed to "after". If it is allowed to execute, one can never be sure of the results obtained -- as you already found out. Actually, I'm a little surprised the trigger above works. I would feel uneasy using it in a real database.

The best option when a trigger *must* access the target table is to hide the table behind a view and write an "instead of" trigger on the view. *That* trigger can access the table all it wants.

Comment: Just a follow up question: Why do we need to use an "instead-of" trigger?

Comment: Because a normal before/after trigger is part of the DML statement being executed. That is why they cannot or should not access the underlying table -- it is in the middle of the Insert, Update or Delete statement that caused the trigger to execute. The "instead of" trigger is an "execute this code instead of the DML statement" operation. So the underlying table is not involved in the Insert, Update or Delete. The trigger code itself must initiate the DML, and it doesn't have to be the same DML. An instead of delete trigger can execute "update table set is_delete = 'Y'" for soft delete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an AFTER trigger, not a BEFORE trigger.  Doing a count(*) "BEFORE" the insert occurs results in zero rows because the data hasn't been inserted yet.