# Trigger vs constraint

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, constraints

Should I use a trigger or a check constraint and can I even create a check constraint that does the following job:

If an article is of type 'Bert', it can have only one row in mytable and only 1 in the stock.
If it is not of type 'Bert', neither of the conditions apply.(can have more rows and more than 1 in the stock)

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('Chip',1,'Bert'); -- Yes
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('Screen',1,'Bert'); -- Yes
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('Chip',1,'Bert'); -- No
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('Cable',2,'Bert'); -- No
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('Keyboard',2,'Non-bert'); -- Yes
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('Keyboard',2,'Non-bert'); -- Yes
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('Keyboard',3,'Non-bert'); -- Yes
```

A trigger like this is causing problems because I am trying to access the base table inside the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_mytable
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.TYPEB = 'Bert')
DECLARE
    L_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT  COUNT(*) INTO L_COUNT
    FROM    MYTABLE 
    WHERE   ARTICLE = :NEW.ARTICLE
        AND TYPEB = :NEW.TYPEB;

    IF L_COUNT > 0  THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Bert already exists!' );
    ELSIF :NEW.STOCK_COUNT > 1 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Can''t insert more than one with type Bert!' );
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I'm not an Oracle guru but I had always assumed that check constrains work at row level :-?

Comment: To me it is unclear what kind of logic you are trying to enforce. Maybe a unique constraint might work for you, if you want certain combinations of values to appear only once in a table.

Comment: This is essentially the same question posed by the same user just a few days before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564976/count-not-working-properly/29574552#29574552

Answer (score 3):

For ensuring there's only one Bert in your table, you can use a combination of a virtual column and a unique constraint on this virtual column. This exploits the fact that a UNIQUE constraint allows multiple NULL values:

```
create table mytable(category varchar2(30), stock number, name varchar2(30));
-- virtual column for checking uniqueness
alter table mytable add is_bert generated always as (
  case name when 'Bert' then 1 else null end
);
alter table mytable add constraint uq_bert unique(is_bert);
```

For ensuring Bert always has stock equal to 1, you can use a CHECK constraint with a simple boolean check (this assumes that name is NOT NULL):

```
-- check constraint for ensuring stock for bert equals 1
alter table mytable add constraint chk_bert_has_stock_one check(
  name != 'Bert' or stock = 1);
```

**Regarding the choice of triggers vs. constraints**, there's a simple rule:

*NEVER* use triggers to enforce business logic. They are difficult to debug, error-prone and will not work correctly in a multi-user environment, see

[AskTom on Triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)

**UPDATE**

The above solution doesn't meet the updated requirements, since (as @LalitKumarB correctly pointed out) it falsely rejects multiple rows for Bert. For this more complicated scenario, I'd use a materialized view with `REFRESH ON COMMIT` (this assumes mytable has a primary key) and two constraints that handle Bert and Non-Bert rows differently:

```
create materialized view log on mytable;

create materialized view mv_mytable 
refresh on commit as 
  select 
     (case when type = 'Bert' then name 
      else null 
      end) as name,
     (case when type = 'Bert' and stock_count != 1 then null 
      else stock_count 
      end) as stock_count
  from mytable;

alter table mv_mytable add constraint uq_bert unique(name);
alter table mv_mytable add constraint chk_bert_stock_count 
  check(stock_count is not null);
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that it will not reject false rows immediately; you won't notice anything's amiss until you try to COMMIT (similar to a deferred constraint).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Frank. I really like the Check constraint to ensure the stock count for 'Bert'. However, I am not sure about creating a virtual column because as far as I know, it is not very practical as I would have to do the insertion by referencing the column names explicitly. However, it is still helpful.

Comment: That will falsely prevent the `'Screen',1,'Bert'` row because it will violate the unique constraint.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Sigh. You're correct (I wish the OP would stop changing the requirements every 5 minutes). I'll try to come up with an updated solution.

Comment: I edited my answer twice, but then I felt hard to cope up with OP's frequent edits, so removed my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If `typeb` ( = 'Bert'? ) should be unique just create an unique index: `create unique index myIndex on mytable ( typeb)` and you'll recieve an duplicate entry error when trying to insert.

Comment: It is not the type that is unique: An article that has a certain type is unique. Please look at the post again. Tried to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

We can use the setup like this one. Please modify Frank Schmitt's is_bert column to check for unique categories bought by Bert.

```
create table mytable(category varchar2(30) , stock number, name varchar2(30));

alter table mytable add is_bert generated always as (
  case  when name='Bert'  and stock=1 then category
            else null end
);
alter table mytable add constraint uq_bert unique(is_bert);
alter table mytable add constraint chk_bert_has_stock_one check(
  name != 'Bert' or stock = 1);


INSERT INTO mytable(category,stock,name) VALUES('Chip',1,'Bert'); -- Yes
INSERT INTO mytable(category,stock,name) VALUES('Screen',1,'Bert'); -- Yes
INSERT INTO mytable(category,stock,name) VALUES('Chip',1,'Bert'); -- No
INSERT INTO mytable(category,stock,name) VALUES('Cable',2,'Bert'); -- No
INSERT INTO mytable(category,stock,name) VALUES('Keyboard',2,'Non-bert'); -- Yes
INSERT INTO mytable(category,stock,name) VALUES('Keyboard',2,'Non-bert'); -- Yes
INSERT INTO mytable(category,stock,name) VALUES('Keyboard',3,'Non-bert'); -- Yes
```

Also a function based index can achieve it, I guess.

```
create table mytable(category varchar2(30) , stock number, name varchar2(30));
alter table mytable add constraint chk_bert_has_stock_one check(
  name != 'Bert' or stock = 1);

  create unique index myfun_index on mytable (case  when name='Bert'  and stock=1 then category
            else null end);
```

Comment: Care to explain why you post a verbatim copy of the first part of my answer as your own?

Comment: @ Frank Schmitt Agreed. I copied the (99%) from  first part of your answer. But my point is to modify it to suite the requirement. Since I modified the logic to suite it to be a complete answer(case  when name='Bert'  and stock=1 then category) I think I can post it as my answer. Still worried?

Comment: Could you please explain in your answer why this approach works (as opposed to mine)? In its current state, it's quite hard to understand (esp. since the column name 'is_bert' is completely misleading in your modified solution).